# @2x images are too large, outside bounds on retina displays

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, retina

I have added assets as described in the apple developer documentation naming my images imagename.png for low res and imagename@2x.png for retina.

I have dragged images into my view on my storyborad and when I run this on a retina display device it seems to automatically use the @2x image, however the image becomes square as it seems to extend outside the bounds that I have set. If I run it on a non-retina device and inside the storyboard the image looks fine.

You can see my issue here, retina is on the left and the storyboard and how it should look is on the right side.

[image]

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: just saying, but for such situation using the `cornerRadius` and `clipToBounds` properties would be a much more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your **imageView** settings in storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Mode was set to Center and it should be Scale To Fill

Comment: @MarkusTenghamn Consider marking the answer as "accepted" as it helps other users to look at correct places and choose the best answers.

Comment: Of course, just had to wait 5 min or whatever the time was :)